# Quais as vantagens das Expressões Lambda presentes no Java 8?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8

O Java 8 será lançado em breve ([março de 2014](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)) e a principal *feature* desta versão são as ***Expressões Lambda***.

Alguém poderia descrever, como diz a pergunta, o que este recurso vai agregar na prática para os desenvolvedores e, se possível, algum exemplo de código comentado?

Comment: Cheguei atrasado, infelizmente já fecharam a sua pergunta. A minha sugestão é simplesmente você pegar algum projeto legal para fazer e começar a experimentar. Dá para aprender rápido e você vai ver que o código fica bem melhor com lambdas. Ele é algo que nem o generics foi há 8 anos atrás: No começo, todo mundo achava que era complicado demais, gambiarrado e desnecessário, mas com o tempo o povão começou a perceber que na verdade era uma coisa muito importante que não dava para entender porque não estava no java desde o início.

Comment: Coloquei [uma questão no meta](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/97/sobre-questoes-de-escopo-amplo) referente a esta pergunta.

Comment: Votei por reabrir, pois para a adoção de lambda teve que ser justificada pelas regras do JCP na JSR-335, e essas justificativas podem ser apresentadas, objetivamente, como resposta aqui.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Expressões lambda são uma funcionalidade comum em muitas linguagens, em particular as que seguem o paradigma [Programação Funcional](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_funcional) (o termo em si vem do [Cálculo Lambda](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_lambda), fundação matemática que sustenta esse paradigma), mas que recentemente vêm sendo introduzidas em linguagens de outros paradigmas (como, no caso, o Imperativo/Orientado por Objetos). Para entendê-las, é necessário conhecer os conceitos de **funções de primeira classe** e **literais**.

Tradicionalmente no Java, um método (função, procedimento) somente existe como membro de uma classe. Isso significa que, embora você possa ter uma variável "apontando" para um objeto, você não pode guardar um método numa variável. Tudo aquilo que é permitido referenciar numa linguagem (no caso objetos ou tipos primitivos), passar como parâmetro para outras funções, etc, é dito ser "de primeira classe".

Outras linguagens, entretanto, permitem que funções e outras coisas mais (como classes) sejam referenciados e passados como argumento. Exemplo usando JavaScript:

```js
function teste() { alert("teste"); }
var x = teste;
x(); // Alerta "teste"
```

O suporte a funções de primeira classe simplifica em muito a construção de certas funções. Por exemplo, se queremos ordenar uma lista, e gostaríamos de especificar um critério específico de comparação, passamos uma função como parâmetro para o método de ordenar:

```js
ordena([...], function(a,b) { /* compara A e B */ });
```

Em vez de ter que criar uma classe específica para conter a tal função:

```java
class MeuComparador implements Comparador {
    int comparar(Object a, Object b) { /* compara A e B */ }
}
ordena([...], new MeuComparador());
```

As expressões lambda vão um passo além, não só permitindo passar funções como parâmetro para outras funções*, mas também permitindo que as mesmas sejam expressas como literais. Um literal é uma notação que representa um valor fixo no código fonte, ou seja, através do uso da própria sintaxe você consegue criar um objeto que de outra forma exigiria a combinação de duas ou mais funcionalidades diferentes. Exemplo (expressões regulares em JavaScript):

```js
var regex = /.../;             // Literal (o resultado já é um objeto RegExp)
var regex = new RegExp("..."); // Não literal (usa-se uma string, uma classe e o
                               // comando "new" para se construir o objeto
```

No Java 8, o literal para uma expressão lambda consiste em uma lista de argumentos (zero ou mais) seguida do operador `->` seguida de uma expressão que deve produzir um valor. Exemplos:

```java
() -> 42              // Não recebe nada e sempre retorna "42"
x -> x*x              // Recebe algo e retorna seu quadrado
(x,y) -> x + y        // Recebe dois valores e retorna sua soma
```

Para entender os detalhes internos, como isso impacta o restante do programa, como é feito a descoberta de tipos, etc, sugiro ler a [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (em inglês), pois se trata de uma funcionalidade ainda nova (pelo menos nessa linguagem). Quanto às vantagens, a principal delas é a **concisão** - fazer mais coisa escrevendo menos código. Com frequência, não há razão para se exigir que uma função esteja sempre acompanhada de uma classe, e o uso dessas expressões evita muitas construções desnecessárias.

*Nota: como apontado por @dstori, a introdução de expressões lambda no Java não tornou as funções primeira-classe, uma vez que essas expressões são convertidas em classes anônimas pelo compilador (ou seja, ainda não é possível fazer referência direta a um método em Java, somente indireta através do objeto que o define).

Answer (score 11):

É uma tentativa (mal sucedida na minha opnião) de inserir uma característica funcional na linguagem. Na prática vai evitar que você tenha que criar classes anônimas de apenas um método, pois é isso que expressões lambda fazem. Adição de Listeners, Runnables, Callables e afins irão ficar menos verbosos.

Ao invés de:

```java
new Thread(new Runnble() {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running...");
  }
}).start();
```

Teremos:

```java
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Running with lambda")).start();
```

Comment: Heheh, "mal sucedida" já? Talvez pudesse ser melhor, mas dê um tempinho para a parada tentar suceder. É visível a melhora nesse exemplo que você deu. =)

Comment: Concordo com a melhora "neste cenário específico" elias, mas ficou devendo em muitos outros casos. Além do mais, em uma estrutura que seja sua (diferente de runnables, listeneres e afins) você terá que criar um (urghhh) interface funcional para usar lambda (urghh de novo).

Comment: "vai evitar que você tenha que criar classes anônimas de apenas um método, pois é isso que expressões lambda fazem" Bem observado! Por um instante pensei que finalmente Java daria suporte a funções de primeira classe, mas vejo que não é o caso...

Comment: Estou trabalhando em um projeto que usa lambdas, e na minha opinião são muito bem sucedidas.

Comment: Eu não acho que será malsucedida, acredito que vai melhorar bastante!

Answer (score 5):

Eu acho que essa pergunta tem um escopo muito grande, e nenhuma resposta que possa ser dada aqui será melhor que a [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#use-case). Mas resumindo bastante, lambdas são construções que possibilitam passar um código como parâmetro.

O benefício é que você não precisa criar uma estrutura formal para especificar este código. Em geral, você precisaria especificar uma classe (anônima ou não) e um método, dentro do qual seu código estaria. Então, com lambdas, você tem apenas o código, que pode ser executado por sua API.

Ao invés de listar vantagens, desvantagens e exemplos, coloco novamente o [link da documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#use-case), que traz muitos detalhes.

Answer (score 4):

Um pequeno exemplo de como  funciona Lambada e a maior vantagem dela !

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList("Java", "Lambda", "Lambda Expression");
```

Temos uma lista de String simples e queremos ordena-la pelo menor tamanho. E como faríamos isso em Java? Bem podemos criar uma classe e nela implementar o Comparator e passá-la como parâmetro no sort ou para não criarmos uma classe só para isso, podemos usar uma classe anônima, mais ou menos assim...

```
Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<String>(){
      public int compare(String valor1, String valor2){
            return valor1.length() - valor2.length();
      }
});
```

Criamos uma lista e estamos a usar o sort da Collections passando a lista que queremos ordenar e um Comparator onde usamos uma classe anônima com a implementação do compare, ele recebe dois valores e na implementação é saber quem é o menor, simples.

Agora a utilizar os conceitos de Lambda Expression, iremos fazer o mesmo código:

```
Collections.sort(lista, (v1, v2) -> v1.length() - v2.length());
```