# Colecção Map<k,v> Metodos

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, collection

**Duvidas sobre os métodos** `replace` : `compute` : `computeIfAbsent` : `computeIfPresent` :`forEach`(resumidamente todos os que fazem uso do `function` ou `biFuntion` dentro do parâmetro de entrada)

1. O `replace` é mesmo necessário? isto é eu sempre que queria substituir um `Value` de uma `Key` eu fazia o `put`, como a chave era a mesma o próprio map substituía. Com esta implementação posso ter problemas?
2. `forEach` sei que serve para percorrer todo o map fazendo acções mas como implemento o parâmetro de entrada(*segundo a documentação* `BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action`) podem passar um exemplo?
3. O `compute` : `computeIfAbsent` : `computeIfPresent` não consegui perceber para que servem podem dar um exemplo de uso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A diferença entre o `put` e o `replace` é que o `put` sempre associa a chave ao valor - mesmo se a chave não existia antes. O `replace` seria então um método de conveniência, para só alterar o valor se a chave está lá - não fazer nada se a chave não existe.

   (no que isso é conveniente, não sei, mas quem usa muito Java deve ter passado por essa situação várias vezes, pra achar que isso ajuda...)
2. O `forEach`foi introduzido na versão 8 junto com o suporte a [lambdas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269/215). Sendo assim, sua forma de utilização é por meio dessa abstração. Exemplo:

   ```
   map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
   ```

   (i.e. você cria variáveis para representar a chave e o valor, e estabelece o código que vai agir sobre cada par chave/valor)

   A propósito, percebi agora que é o [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) - e não o `replace` - que recebem um `BiFunction` como parâmetro. Seu uso é para atualizar não somente um, mas **todos** os elementos de um `Map`:

   ```
   map.replaceAll((k, v) -> v * v); // Substitui cada valor pelo seu quadrado
   ```
3. Segundo [essa postagem](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/02/14/java-8-friday-goodies-map-enhancements/), "frequentemente nós pegamos um valor de um map, fazemos alguns cálculos sobre ele e colocamos ele de volta no map. O código pode ser prolixo, e difícil de fazer de forma correta se concorrência está envolvida." Esses métodos então servem para ajudar nisso: atualizar um determinado valor do `Map`.

   ```
   map.compute(minhaChave, (k, v) -> v * v); // Substitui o valor pelo seu quadrado
   ```

   O `computeIfPresent` faz o mesmo, mas só quando a chave já está presente no `Map` (o `compute` faz com ou sem a chave presente, passando um valor `null` se a chave está ausente). Já o `computeIfAbsent` é o contrário - só pro caso da chave estar ausente. Nesse caso, como já sabemos que não tem valor, não faz sentido o lambda receber dois parâmetros, então somente a chave é considerada:

   ```
   map.computeIfAbsent(minhaChave, (k) -> 42);
   ```