# Criar classes tirando vantagem do lambda

Tags: java, java-8, expressões-lambda

Após ler [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269/quais-as-vantagens-das-express%C3%B5es-lambda-presentes-no-java-8) feita pelo [utluiz♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz), pude entender, mesmo que de uma forma mais superficial, um pouco da utilidade das expressões *lambda* adicionadas ao JDK 8.

Porém, além dos exemplos citados de como simplificar recursos que a linguagem já possui (como a ordenação usando `Collections` e o uso de `Runnables`, onde o próprio netbeans já sugere a modificação em alguns casos), não consigo imaginar um cenário onde eu poderia fazer implementações próprias que tirem vantagem do *lambda*.

Em que tipo de cenário eu poderia tirar vantagem do *lambda*, implementando minhas próprias classes, fazendo o uso deste recurso?

Comment: Não sei o que pretende como resposta mas, resumidamente, "lambdas são construções que possibilitam passar um código como parâmetro."(jpkrohling, [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277/2541)), então use-os  nesse cenário.

Comment: Lambdas são a última bolacha do pacote e uma linguagem sem eles é pobre, demoraram demais para entrar em Java e como resultado tem uma legião de devs que não compreende. As utilidades são infinitas e os códigos de um dos livros clássicos da computação [Structure and interpretation of computer programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) é quase que inteiramente feito em cima de lambdas (embora a linguagem base seja lisp os exemplos serve para qualquer uma que possua lambdas).

Comment: Boa pergunta. Uma coisa é saber o que é e como usar com a API existente. Outra bem diferente é fazer uso do recurso na sua própria API. Entretanto, entender lambdas é muito simples mesmo para quem nunca ouviu falar, desde que o conceito de listeners ou callbacks e classes anônimas seja familiar. Vou adicionar uma resposta em breve.

Comment: Mes passado eu fiz umas alterações no código para remover uma herança mal definida. Ficou bem legal, vou ver se eu posto amanhã aqui

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Entender e usar lambdas em Java é muito simples mesmo para quem nunca ouviu falar, desde que se tenha uma boa base sobre alguns aspectos da linguagem, conceito de listeners ou callbacks e classes anônimas.

## Consideração inicial

Muita gente diz que lambdas fizeram muita falta no Java até a versão 8, mas tenho duas colocações a fazer sobre isso:

1. Lambdas são açúcar sintático, o mesmo poderia e era feito usando interfaces com um método.
2. Sintaxe não é tudo. Veja o caso do JavaScript, por exemplo, você pode simular lambdas passando funções, mas não tem facilidade alguma de sintaxe.

Vou explicar abaixo alguns tipos de problemas que eram resolvidos usando interfaces e depois vou descrever as soluções equivalentes usando lambdas.

Mais adiante, irei descrever alguns cenários onde lambdas são úteis ao projetar e usar APIs.

## No início existiam as interfaces

Vou usar dois exemplos.

### Processamento demorado

No primeiro temos uma rotina que faz um processamento demorado e precisa fazer algo personalizado em algum momento.

A interface:

```
interface MeChameQuandoAcabar {
    void acabei();
}
```

O método:

```
void processamentoDemoradoAssimcrono(MeChameQuandoAcabar callback) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //faz algo muito demorado
            callback.acabei();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Basicamente o método executa algo numa thread e, ao final, chama o método `acabei()` da nossa interface funcional.

Para chamar o método de processamento devemos criar uma classe implementando a interface. Entretanto, é bom lembrar que, além das classes regulares, o Java tem ainda classes internas e classes anônimas.

Com isso em mente, podemos fazer algo próximo aos lambdas usando classes anônimas:

```
processamentoDemoradoAssimcrono(new MeChameQuandoAcabar() {
    @Override
    public void acabei() {
        System.out.println("fui...");
    }
});
```

E então o código acima imprimirá `fui...` quando acabar o processamento.

### Processamento personalizado

Outra possibilidade para você usar lambdas é quando quer implementar algo que lembre o Strategy Pattern, isto é, você tem algum algoritmo e um ou mais passos dele podem ser personalizados.

A interface:

```
interface FacaIssoTambem {
    String fazerAlgoAMais(String s);
}
```

O método:

```
static List<String> facaAlgumaCoisa(List<String> lista, FacaIssoTambem m) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : lista) {
        s = "prefixo:" + s;
        s = m.fazerAlgoAMais(s);
        result.add(s);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Basicamente o método recebe uma lista de strings e adiciona um prefixo a cada item, retornando uma nova lista.

Com nossa interface funcional, você pode fazer mais alguma coisa. Exemplo:

```
facaAlgumaCoisa(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"), new FacaIssoTambem() {
    @Override
    public String fazerAlgoAMais(String s) {
        return s + ":sufixo";
    }
});
```

A chamada acima vai retornar uma lista com os itens `[prefixo:1:sufixo, prefixo:2:sufixo, prefixo:3:sufixo]`.

## Então surgiram os lambdas

Um lambda em Java, nada mais é do que uma forma mais amigável de declarar uma classe anônima que implementa uma interface chamada *interface funcional*.

Uma interface funcional contém apenas um método e é boa prática anotá-la com `@FunctionalInterface`, mas apenas para deixar a intenção explícita no código, pois funciona mesmo sem isso.

Assim, os dois exemplos acima poderiam ter as chamadas aos métodos substituídos por lambdas.

## Processamento demorado

A nova chamada poderia ser assim:

```
processamentoDemoradoAssimcrono(() -> System.out.println("fui..."));
```

O lambda, `() -> System.out.println("fui...")` significa o seguinte:

- `()` diz que não há parâmetros
- `->` separa a declaração dos parâmetros do "corpo" do método
- o restante é o corpo do método, que se for apenas um comando não precisa ser declarado como um bloco usando `{` e `}`.

Basicamente, isso é o mesmo instanciar uma classe anônima e implementar o método existente.

## Processamento personalizado

A nova chamada poderia ser assim:

```
facaAlgumaCoisa(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"), s -> s + ":sufixo")
```

Nesse caso, o lambda é `s -> s + ":sufixo"`.

Da mesma forma que no exemplo anterior, ele nada mais é do que uma implementação anônima da interface `FacaIssoTambem` e seu método `fazerAlgoAMais`.

Por isso, temos o parâmetro `s` do lambda sendo equivalente ao parâmetro do método na interface. Da mesma forma, a expressão `s + ":sufixo"` retorna uma String, que é o tipo esperado pelo retorno do método.

Faça isso diferente e você vai ver um erro do compilador. O lambda tem que declarar os parâmetros e retornar valor de forma compatível com o método da interface, como se você realmente estivesse sobrescrevendo o método.

## Outras aplicações

### Decorar a execução de um trecho de código

Outra aplicação interessante inclui em "decorar" trechos de código com alguma funcionalidade comum.

Um exemplo que acho bem interessante é o de executar comandos dentro de uma transação sem sujar seu código com um monte de `try/catch/finally`:

```
executarComTransacao(() -> {
    updateTabela1();
    updateTabela2();
});
```

E então você implementa o método acima criando uma lógica de controle transacional que será usada em todo o sistema.

Enfim, sempre que você tiver uma forma específica de execução de código que envolva uma lógica comum (assíncrona, demarcada, condicional), lambdas são interessantes para facilitar o uso.

### Execução condicional

Outro exemplo envolve a execução condicional de código.

Vamos supor que em vários locais de um sistema você tem que executar condicionalmente certas ações que são diferentes, mas todas baseadas na mesma condição.

Você poderia repetir `if`s em todo lugar assim:

```
if (condicao) fazIsso();
...
if (condicao) fazAquilo();
```

Uma alternativa com lambdas seria:

```
executarCondicionalmente(() -> fazIsso());
...
executarCondicionalmente(() -> fazAquilo());
```

O método poderia ser algo assim:

```
public void executarCondicionalmente(Runnable r) {
    if (condicao) r.run();
}
```

Perceba que o tipo de interface ou o nome do método somente importa onde você está declarando. Do ponto de vista de quem passa um lambda, isso não importa.

### Postergar execução

Você também pode usar lambdas para expressar valores que você não quer que sejam calculados antes da chamada ao método.

Um exemplo simples está na API `Optional<T>`.

Suponha que você quer carregar dados de algum lugar e esta pode ser uma operação demorada. Caso a rotina não encontra os dados, o sistema deve então carregar um backup.

A abordagem tradicional seria algo assim:

```
String data = loadHugeData();
if (data == null) {
    data = loadHugeDataBackup();
}
```

Note que nós não queremos chamar o método de backup a menos que o retorno do primeiro método seja nulo.

Se pensarmos um pouco mais em programação funcional, poderemos refatorar os método métodos usando `Optional`, assim:

```
Optional<String> loadHugeData() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(...);
}
```

Então lógica principal pode ser simplificada assim:

```
String data = loadHugeData().orElseGet(() -> loadHugeDataBackup());
```

A ideia do `Optional` é que você nunca retorna `null`. Se não houver dados, ele deve retornar um valor vazio.

Quando você chama o método `orElseGet` passando um lambda, o `Optional` vai verificar se ele tem um valor e, se tiver, vai retorná-lo imediatamente. Caso contrário, ele vai então executar o lambda e recuperar os dados de backup.

Comment: Se for necessário passar 2 parâmetros, tem que ser dentro da `()` dessa forma: `(param1, param2) -> System.out.println(acabou...)`? Ou isso não existe?

Comment: @Diego É exatamente isso. Basta usar parêntesis.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ideia do `executarComTransacao`!