# Qual é a finalidade dos parênteses vazios numa declaração lambda?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Criei um exemplo de uma declaração Lambda sem argumentos, entretanto, estou com duvidas referente a omissão do parêntese vazio `()` na declaração.

Veja o exemplo:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDelegate d = () => 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Ola mundo lambda! :]");
                            };
        d();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**As minhas duvidas são as seguintes.**

1. Qual é a finalidade dos parênteses vazios `()`?
2. E em que ele implica na declaração?
3. Ele assume o comportamento de uma variável?

Comment: Pelo que entendi da [explicação do @utluiz](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112804/28595), significa que não há nenhum parametro sendo passado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É para indicar que a função anônima que ela representa não tem nenhum parâmetro. Foi o jeito que se arrumou para a sintaxe não ficar manca, já que sempre tem que ter alguma coisa antes do `=>` que separa os parâmetros do corpo da da função.

Não há nada diferente além disso em relação às outras *lambdas*.

Em tese poderiam deixar sem, mas fica esquisito e poderia criar alguma ambiguidade no futuro, se é que já não tem e eu não percebi. *Design* de linguagem exige bom gosto e pensar no futuro.

Pensa na função comum, normalmente ela terias parênteses sempre, tendo um parâmetro ou não. Por que uma *lambda* não precisa? Ora, porque ela é uma sintaxe de conveniência, quanto menos escrever melhor (e nem é por causa da digitação, é para dar mais legibilidade mesmo, e ir direto ao ponto). Então ela evita os parenteses sempre que possível, esse não é um caso possível.

Outro caso onde eles são necessários é quando tem mais de um parâmetro. Então a conveniência fica só para um parâmetro, que é o caso mais usado.

Não precisava das chaves.

```
MyDelegate d = () => Console.WriteLine("Ola mundo lambda! :]");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Syntax.cs).

Veja que esquisito, mas poderiam ter aceito assim:

```
MyDelegate d = => Console.WriteLine("Ola mundo lambda! :]");
```

Imagine a pessoa esquecer o espaço entre os dois `=`.

Comment: Poderiam ter usado o `void` acho q daria mais sentido no codigo: `MyDelegate d = void => Console.WriteLine("Ola mundo lambda! :]");`

Comment: Até poderiam, nas acho que não tem cara de C#, que inclusive quer ficar mais próximo das linguagens funcionais q usam assim.