# Como funciona o item.setOnClickListener(view -> method())

Tags: java, android

Como funciona esse `item.setOnClickListener(view -> method());`?
Nunca tinha visto esse tipo de chamada, ví hoje e fiquei curioso com essa `view`, de onde ela vem? Como esse tipo de chamada funciona?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LineHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s, %d - %s",
                mUsers.get(position).getName(),
                mUsers.get(position).getAge(),
                mUsers.get(position).getCity()
        ));

        holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener(view -> updateItem(position));
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(view -> removerItem(position));
    }
```

Comment: O nome dessa expressão é `lambda`. Ela é bastante utilizada com classes anônimas (tanto no Java 8+, quanto no JavaScript ES6 (arrow functions)), a vantagem dela é reduzir o código e deixa-lo mais limpo. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Olhando somente esse trecho, o *moreButton* deveria ser executado somente com um clique.

Comment: Pse, não funciona de jeito nenhum, eu fiz meu próprio recyclerView e tb n funcionou, apenas c dois cliques

Comment: No site onde está o código quando o cara faz o clique a função é chamada, mas aqui simplesmente não funciona

Comment: Ah, esquece a parte do duplo clique, resolvi aqui, foi erro meu, tinha colocado o evento de clique no recyclerView, então a ação dele estava a frente, esse era o erro

Comment: Se a parte do duplo clique era outro problema não relacionado comvem atualizar a pergunta removendo isso, para evitar que pessoas tentem resolver um problema que não existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe em questão é um *lambda*, sintaxe introduzida no Java 8, explicada em detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112804/22247).

Escrever isto no Java 8:

```
holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener(view -> updateItem(position));
```

É o equivalente ao que era escrito assim no Java 7:

```
holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        updateItem(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Classe ViewHolder estruturada

```
/**
 * A classe ViewHolder internamente guarda a view
 */
public class LineHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    Button moreButton,deleteButton;

    /**
     * contrutor onde a View é adicionada
     * E inflado os demais elementos da view
     * @param itemView
     */
    public LineHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        morebutton =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
        deleteButton =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

    }
}
```

Onde o Holder é criado e inserido sua view

```
/**
 * Aqui que a View do Holder é inflada
 */
public LineHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
    return new LineHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_line_holder, parent, false));
}
```

Então vc atualiza o holder

```
/**
 * Como os Holders são views reaproveitadas, é necessario fazer sua atualização quando ele pe chamado, e este metodo é para fazer a atualização dos recursos da view
 * @param holder
 * @param position
 */
public void onBindViewHolder(LineHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText("some text");

    //chamda da função lambda: necessario java 8 para executar ela
    holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener(view -> updateItem(position));

    //chamada padrão
    holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            updateItem(position);
        }
    });

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(view -> removerItem(position));
}
```